# No sound after laptop lid closed

Tags: sound

I used to have the problem where my HP laptop wouldn't wake up after the lid had been closed but I've just upgraded to 21.10 and that issue is sorted, however when I open the lid now I have no sound whatsoever!  The only way I know to get it back is to restart the laptop which is exactly what I had to do with the wake-up problem.

Any ideas?

inxi -SA gives (after opening lid and finding no sound):-

```
  Host: eric-HP-Laptop Kernel: 5.13.0-22-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: GNOME 40.5 Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
  driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x 
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-22-generic running: yes 
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `inxi -SA` *after* opening the lid again? (**Note:** You may need to install `ixni` prior to this)

Comment: Ok, all done :-)